# How is a SyncAdapter triggered by the system?

Tags: android

I have an application which uses a SyncAdapter to make a REST call to remote server, then use a Content Provider to persist the updates to the local SQLLite DB.

I can trigger the call by going the Accounts & Sync, then selecting my adapter, and using the Resync button to trigger the call

How does the system know when (how often) to make the onPerformSync() call in the SyncAdapter?

I am logging on the service to which the REST call resolves, but I am not seeing any calls unless I do it manually as described above.

Btw, i am running in the emulator at the moment, i have not installed this on a device yet

Answer (score 1):

From your ContentProvider you must let your SyncAdapter know there was a change to the dataset.

You do this by calling [notifyChange()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#notifyChange%28android.net.Uri,%20android.database.ContentObserver,%20boolean%29)

For example within your ContentProviders insert() method:

> getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(rowUri, null);

It may not sync right away, but that is just how SyncAdapters work. The system decides when is a good time to sync. Usually it happens relatively fast in my experience. Of course you may not want it to sync every single time a change happens in your database, but you can always put code into your performSync to control the frequency of the syncs.

Hope this helps someone :)